# I see GCP App Engine instances deployed but cannot access them via SSH from gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to debug a problem with deploying an Express server, and I need to see the logs. I can't do it locally because the issue is my launch configuration/app.yaml.

So below is a picture of my console, where I can see the instance.

Also in the terminal I can use gcloud and see the same instance, but when I try to ssh into it or enable debug the CLI tells me there are no such instnaces

[image: These are my GCP console for App Engine where I can see the current instances]

[image: When I run gcloud app instances I can see a list of the instances in GAE]

[[image: Trying to enable debug mode on the instances][3]]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add instance id after the command

```
gcloud app instances enable-debug 0061...
```

Comment: I tried this and got a similar error:  ERROR: (gcloud.app.instances.enable-debug) No instances match the given specification.

All instances: []

Comment: @nerbit comparing the standard and flexible, ssh debugging is not supported on std env
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments
are you using flex ?